# How do I access a numpy array in embedded python from c++?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, c-api

What would be a good way to access a 2dim numpy array in c++? I've already checked out the numpy/c api and some other posts but that doesn't brought me further. Here's the situation:

I defined in a python file called Testfile.py the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
```

Now, I would like to access this array in c++ to use it for further calculations. Here is what i did so far. 
Note: For simplicity, i left out error handling and reference counting code snippets.

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_APINPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL cool_ARRAY_API
#include <Python.h>
#include <arrayobject.h> // numpy!
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(){

// Name of input-file
char pyfilename[] = "Testfile";

// initilaize python interpreter
Py_Initialize();
import_array(); 

// load input-file
PyObject *pyName = PyUnicode_FromString(pyfilename);
PyObject *pyModule = PyImport_Import(pyName);

// import my numpy array object
char pyarrayname[] = "A";
PyObject *obj = PyObject_GetAttrString(pyModule, pyarrayname);

//------------------------------------------------------------
// The Problem starts here..

// Array Dimensions
npy_intp Dims[] = { PyArray_NDIM(obj) }; // array dimension
Dims[0] = PyArray_DIM(obj, 0); // number of rows
Dims[1] = PyArray_DIM(obj, 1); // number of columns

// PyArray_SimpleNew allocates the memory needed for the array.
PyObject *ArgsArray = PyArray_SimpleNew(2, Dims, NPY_DOUBLE);

// The pointer to the array data is accessed using PyArray_DATA()
double *p = (double *)PyArray_DATA(ArgsArray);

for (int i = 0; i<Dims[0]; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<Dims[1]; j++)
        {
             p[i * Dims[1] + j] = *((int *)PyArray_GETPTR2(obj, i, j));
        }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------


Py_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

I use python 3.6 and MSVC 2015.

**EDIT:** I added the headers i use and changed the problem formulation a bit.

**EDIT:** I added the proposed solution strategies provided by **Swift** and **Alan Stokes**

Comment: What does it mean to call an array?

Comment: For me it means, to use previously defined data. For example, first i define an integer int a=1; later on, i use/call this variable somewhere else in the code e.g. int b; b=a+1; I'm not sure if the word "call" is the right term :P

Comment: In my case, i define a array called A in python, using numpy. Now i would like to use/call this array inside my c++ code to use it for some other calculus. :)

Comment: That's not what "call" normally means; you call a function, but you access a variable or array element. An array is not callable in the usual sense. `PyArray_GETPTR2` might help you.

Comment: @Alan Stokes ah, that sounds like LUA and Python specifics.. as they use calling   (that is, parenthesis) to access everything

Comment: You should provide a working example, that one is missing way how you initialize your program (and that might be essential to the problem), what headers are included. just main() isn't enough

Comment: @AlanStokes: I guess you rigth with the term access.  Thank your for the tip with PyArray_GETPTR2. I will try that one.

Comment: @Swift: I use the following headers : #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_APINPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#define PY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL cool_ARRAY_API
#include <Python.h>
#include <arrayobject.h> // numpy!
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

Comment: I added the headers i use into the code above and changed the problem description.

Comment: @AlanStokes: PyArray_GETPTR2 works! :) Is there a way to get the number of rows and columns of an array with a similar command like PyArray_SIZE(obj)?

Comment: @stevula that one accesses  _single element of array, but surely it should work although if you will try use entire array by calling it for EACH element, it may cause huge performance issue. What you did with trying to "call" data, was wrong . but you can also use p pointer to access whole array, PyArray_DIM will give you dimensions

Comment: @swift: Thank you for the tips! :) they really helped me a lot! Regarding your last commend and the answer you posted before. I thougth you mean that  i should call  PyArray_GETPTR2(obj, i, j) within those for-loops in order to shift the data within obj into p? Could you explain me how to use the pointer p to access the whole array as you described? The array dimensions i have to deal with are going to be of size 10000x10000 so performance could be a problem. :P

Comment: I added your proposed solution strategies into the code i posted in the problem description. I hope this is what you meant!?

Comment: @Swift: Do you mean that i should just use int *p = (int *)PyArray_DATA(obj); directly?

Comment: @stevula noo, you can access  both your new array and your  python arry through PyArray_DATA just in same way. And are you sure you need another array in python objects for C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

After you  access array by

```
double *p = (double*)PyArray_DATA(ArgsArray);
int* pA = (int*)PyArray_DATA(obj);
```

you can work with it like with array. What are dimensions?

```
int height = PyArray_DIM(obj, 0);
int width = PyArray_DIM(obj, 1);
```

Now you can use that pointer to access data in array

```
for ( int i = 0; y<height; y++) 
{ 
   for (int j = 0; x<width; x++) 
   { 
      p[i * width + j] = pA[i * width + j];
   }
}
```

Actually, if you just need to copy array, use memcpy or std::copy at this point.

Tbh, I'd considered to use boost.python instead, but it's my own preference.

Comment: Instead of using `pA[i * width + j]`, is there a way to have a multi-dimensional array? E.g. accessing it like `pA[i][j]`?

Comment: @decadenza by writing some wrapper with operators that do that? I won't try and risk answer in general case, any casts can lead to aliasing breach. I think boost offers that, I just never used that extension.

Comment: Many thanks. I am actually working on Python. I am writing some C++ extensions do do operations on big matrices but I found extremely painful to work with one dimensional arrays and surprised that C++ has got nothing off the shelf to do this. On the other side I do not want to add unnecessary payload.